# Not Getting a refresh_token

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

This is in continuation with [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48074857/outlook-notification-subscription-using-azure-webhook-domain-not-found).

I had to finally get the user in question the admin role and then I created a new application registration at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/

The application was granted admin consent by hitting `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?..` endpoint with the required parameters.

Everything works fine and I was even able to create the outlook mail subscription for this user.

The issue though is, the endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` is not giving me the `refresh_token`. I tried including the `offline_access` (reference - http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/) in the scope for getting the authorization code, but got the following error -

> AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application.

So the situation is like this -

- If I use v1.0 endpoint, I get both access and refresh token but
  hitting the endpoint
  `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('dummy@example.com')/subscriptions`

  sends back a `401 Unauthorized`. I understand that the endpoint targets v2.0 but I didn't find one for v1.0.
- However, If I use v2.0 endpoint, I am able to create the subscription but only get the access token which is shortly lived and this creates a need for going through this whole process again which I don't want.

Comment: Have you repeated the Admin Consent with the full set of scopes?

Comment: One thing that jumps out to me from your question is that you have registered a v2 app (i.e. at the apps.dev.microsoft.com portal), but you mention v1 endpoints (the login.microsoftonline.com URLs don't have v2.0).

Comment: @juunas - The endpoint was mistakenly mentioned to be that of v1.0. I have updated my question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It turned out that Daniel's answer is what I was looking for. Didn't pay enough attention to the available permissions else would have seen the offline_access option there. As a side question, the response includes ext_expires_in with a value roughly around 73 hrs. Any idea if this refers to the refresh_token life span?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a commenter indicated, you've registered an Azure AD v2.0 application, and are calling the Azure AD v1.0 endpoints. This isn't strictly the problem you're facing, but I recommend reconfiguring your auth endpoints to be for v2.0.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

I think the issue you may be running into is not configuring static permissions before calling the admin consent endpoint.  One of the new features of Azure AD v2.0 is dynamic consent & scopes that allow you to ask for new permissions when requesting them; however, for admin consent you must configure these as static permissions.

You can configure static permissions in Azure AD v2.0 inside [the App Reg Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) through the UI below:

[image]

Then try hitting the admin consent endpoint again, and finally re-requesting the refresh token with the `offline_access` scope.

Comment: @ Daniel - Thanks for the solution.This indeed was the issue it turned out. I had to include offline_access in the delegated permissions.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Dobalian, @gkb. How did you guys send the `offline_access` scope to the token endpoint? Based on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0#4-get-an-access-token) the scope is different and I will get an error `The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid`

Comment: The auth flow you linked (called "client credentials") is completely non-interactive and will not produce a refresh token. The refresh token is really intended to minimize user interaction as a long term artifact representing a user session. In client credentials, you'll always have the app's credentials (appid/secret or cert) and can continue to use these whenever the Access Token expires.

Comment: If you were trying to get tokens in the delegated or user context, you may be using the wrong protocol. If you're on a client, you'll be looking for the "authorization code flow" or "implicit flow" on browser-based apps or "on-behalf-of" if you're executing this on a service in the user context.